# Criterion for irrational numbers of constant type 2

Tags: diophantine-approximation, continued-fractions, discrepancy-theory

From Kuiper's and Niederreiter's book *Uniform distribution of sequences*, Ch.2, § 3, I learn that an irrational number $\alpha\in \mathbf{R}\smallsetminus \mathbf{Q}$ is of *constant type $\eta$* if the following supremum is finite:
$$
\eta = \{\gamma>0 : \liminf_{q\to \infty} q^\gamma \langle q \alpha\rangle=0\},
$$
where $q$ ranges over integers and 
$$
\langle x\rangle = \inf_{z\in \mathbf{Z}} |x-z| .
$$
The Thue–Siegel–Roth Theorem tells us that if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then $\alpha$ has constant type $1$.

> Is there a reasonable description of the set of real numbers with constant type at least $2$?

Comment: Are you asking for a "reasonable description of all such numbers" or "a large set of examples that have a reasonable description"? To illustrate, as you've noted, all algebraic numbers have constant type 1, but the complete set of real numbers of constant type 1 probably doesn't has a "reasonable description", since it's a set of full measure with uncountable complement.

Comment: Do you mean $\ \eta:=\sup\{\ldots\}\ $ ?